# Parallax images jumpy with skrollr in IOS

Tags: ios, parallax, skrollr

I have a fun parallax site at [Totalsportsus.com/wordpress](http://totalsportsus.com/wordpress) and I can't seem to get skrollr to play nice with my ipad mini.  It is functional, except for when I am scrolling down the page it will jump down near the bottom.  My footer is also missing and it may be related.   Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try debugging this with https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/wiki/Tips#debugging-mobile (which is outdated since Chrome 32, see http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/12/03/google-launches-beta-chrome-devtools-mobile-lets-developers-debug-web-apps-via-emulation-screencasting/#!svtBs)

Answer (score 0):

regarding the "jump" immediately to the bottom I had the same issue. It helped me to set the "mobileDeceleration"-Option to something much higher (0.5) than the default value (0.004) - see https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#mobiledeceleration0004

Your second problem (which I also encountered) could be related to the option "forceHeight". I circumvented it by checking if it's iPad in JS, adding a class to the body and positioning the footer in a different way.

Hope this helps.